# Extracting HTML with beautifulSoup error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: the code im working on]

So here is the code im using to extract at first the time at the upper-left.

```
import qgrid
import webbrowser
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.meteo.gr/cf.cfm?city_id=14') #sending the request to take the html file.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') #creating beautifulSoup object of the html code.

four_days = soup.find(id="prognoseis")#PINPOINTING to the section that i want to focus (the outer).

#Selecting specific elements , having as my base the seven_day.
periods = [p.get_text() for p in four_days.select(".perhour-rowmargin .innerTableCell-fulltime")]


#creating a Data Frame via pandas to print it TABLE-like.
import pandas as pd
weather = pd.DataFrame({"period ": periods})
print weather
```

I looked up a good tutorial to start get the hang of it. 
at the four_days object i hold the part of html code thats included in 'prognoseis', thats where the info i want is.
After at the periods object i choose the element that includes the info i want and as a second argument i specify which exaxtly text i want to extract.

The code runs and gives me empty.

Comment: The element has **two** classes, `perhour` and `rowmargin`, not a single class named `perhour-rowmargin`

Comment: lol, didnt know that, thanks @MartijnPieters that solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding dashes between class names, where no such dashes exist. The `<tr>` element you are selecting has two classes, `perhour` and `rowmargin`, but you are selecting on a non-existing class `perhour-rowmargin`. The same applies to the `td` elements; they have separate classes `fulltime` and `innerTableCell`

Just pick one or the other for both; the following returns the cells you want:

```
four_days.select(".perhour .fulltime")
```

You probably also want to remove the extra newlines around each cell data; add `strip=True` to the `get_text()` calls:

```
[p.get_text(strip=True) for p in four_days.select(".perhour .fulltime")]
```

Comment: Yea as martin stated thats the answer, ill accept it. I just didnt knew how the annotation works. Thanks.

Comment: you are a lifesaver